# Android Application In C# , Toast message - XAMRIN

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, toast

So I was trying to do a simple application. I started first by doing the login form.

The problem is that the toast message wont show. I made it show earlier today but mixed up. I'm new to C# for android, appreciate your help already.

The username is set to be an email Type: dude@gmail.com
The password is set to be a password type: example123

A toast is defined as welcome without a Show method called in within the actual declaration.

Here is the code:

```
    using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace VancersLoginBotV1
{
    [Activity (Label = "VancersLoginBotV1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it

            Button btnlogin = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1);
            EditText txtEmail = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText1);
            EditText txtPassword = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editText2);




            btnlogin.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
            {
                Toast welcome = Toast.MakeText (this, "Welcome to the application", ToastLength.Short);
                if (txtEmail.Text == "dude@gmail.com" && txtPassword.Text == "example123")      
                {
                    welcome.Show();
                }


            };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Man this works, maybe just do a restart (usually helps :) )

Comment: @kirotab It didn't :(

Comment: Maybe try a new project, and just log your variables, or debug them, for example see if they show the same that you enter. Easiest to just put a breakpoint at a line inside the click event .